# How to test if a value is valid for a QFlags

Tags: qt, flags, qenum

Let's say I have this flag:

```
enum MyEnum
{
  AAA = 1,
  BBB = 2,
  CCC = 4,
  DDD = 8
};
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS( MyFlags, MyEnum )
Q_FLAG( MyFlags )
```

How can I test if a value is valid?

i.e. I'd expected -1 or 16 to be invalid.

For enum, this can be achieved with [QMetaEnum::valueToKey](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html#valueToKey) which returns a nullptr.
But for flags, [QMetaEnum::valueToKeys](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html#valueToKeys) always return a byte array, which has a combination of all the flags (it seems so).

Is there a way to check for the validity of a flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp.html#_ZNK9QMetaEnum11valueToKeysEi) looks like a naive AND operation over the enumeration values. So, in the case of -1 (0x FFFF FFFF), the output from `QMetaEnum::valueToKeys()` will be `AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD`. In the case of 16 (0b 0001 0000), an empty byte array is returned.

One way you can check the validity of the initial value is to convert the returned keys back to value using `QMetaEnum::keysToValue()`. If the returned value from `QMetaEnum::keysToValue()` is equal to the initial value, the initial value should be valid.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto meta_enum = QMetaEnum::fromType<MyFlags>();
    int value_before = 17;
    QByteArray keys = meta_enum.valueToKeys(value_before);
    qDebug() << keys;
    int value_after = meta_enum.keysToValue(keys);
    qDebug() << value_after;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

In the code above, for initial value 17 (0b 0001 0001), the returned keys is `AAA`, and `value_after` is 1

Comment: Solution is good if you want to check combination of flags. But if you want to check exact value of flag maybe it is better to iterate every key and check it manually. For example value `3` is the valid combination of flags but there is no flag with value `3`

Comment: Looks like `valueToKey` can check exact flag value so it is no need to iterate every key anyway.